# How to print image url in foreach

Tags: 7, theming, uri, media

I successfully print the image url for a individual images by the following:

```
$file = file_load($node->field_hp_slideshow_image['und'][0]['fid']);
                print file_create_url($file->uri);
```

How can I do something similar but display the url of multiple images in a for or for each loop? Below I have this but it doesn't work:

```
<?php $slide_image = $node->field_hp_slideshow_image['und'];
    $slide_url = $node->field_hp_slideshow_link['und'];
    $file = file_load($node->field_hp_slideshow_image['und'][0]['fid']);
    print $field_hp_slideshow_image['und'][0]['filename'];
    print file_create_url($file->uri);
?>
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($slide_image); ++$i): ?>
    <div class="slideContent">
        <a href="<?php print $slide_url[$i]['url']; ?>">
        <img src="<?php print $base_url . "/" . $path . "/" . $slide_image['filename']; ?>" alt="" />
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Install [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) and change the format to its url. To do so create a view of set of nodes, select the image as the field and change its format to `URL`. You can also change the format to URL in the manage display of the content type.